# Subtraction using 1 textbox visualbasic

Tags: vb.net

Could someone please check my code? i don't seem to get the correct answer after the initial run of my code. 
i want it would be like.

`5-1=4` then if i press the minus button again and i want the new value of my textbox to be subtracted from the difference which in case is 4.

i'm getting the right answer from the 1st process but not when i want to subtract another value from my difference.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If C <> 0 Then
            Dif = C - Val(TextBox1.Text)
            C = Dif
            Label1.Text = Dif
            TextBox1.Clear()
        End If
        C = Val(TextBox1.Text)
        TextBox1.Clear()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Why tag this C# and use a pseudo tag in the title of Visual Basic?

Comment: the version of VB you're using could well be useful.

Comment: ok my bad wrong tagged. corrected :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're trying to accomplish exactly, but there are several problems with your code. Unless it's initialized elsewhere, the first time you click Button2 the variable 'C' is zero, so the 'If' instruction is ignored, C gets the value from the textbox and then clears the textbox.

On a *second* click C has value (assuming that textbox wasn't empty in the first place) and then you substract the content of Textbox1 (assuming it has something) from the value of 'C', and then display it into a label.

Wouldn't it be simpler to assign the contents of TextBox1 and TextBox2 to two variables (checking in the process to see if those contents are valid, i.e. numeric) and then display the result of substracting both variables into Label1?

Comment: what I'm trying to accomplish is use just one textbox on my form. and i want to make it possible to subtract another number(or multiple numbers) from my previous previous answer. isnt my code logically correct? i've assigned the value of C=Dif. so that on my next click, the new value of textbox1 will be subtracted from the value of C(the computed answer from the 1st computation). then label1 will display it.

Comment: Let's say C is 80, and you enter a "20" inside TextBox1. You enter inside the IF, perform your calculations, which give you: Dif = 60, C = 60, Label1.Text = 60. Then you clear Textbox1. Then you get OUT of the IF, and what do you do next? Assign the value of TextBox1.Text to C, BUT YOU JUST CLEARED IT, so C = 0. Maybe what you want to do is to get the content of Label1 inside C, BEFORE the IF? Like this: C = Val(Label1.Text).